# How to Overcome Errors Thrown by mmsystem.h

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2005

I am not able to get out of these simple bugs, but would be great full if some one could answer to weed out from these errors. I included windows.h and some other necessary headers but couldn't able get out of it.

Snippet of errors:

```
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'MMVERSION' 
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*' 
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ms' 
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in `mmsystem.h`, lines 112 and 113:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
typedef UINT        MMVERSION;  /* major (high byte), minor (low byte) */
```

So be sure to include `windows.h` befor including `mmsystem.h`, and if it does not help, try `#define`ing `_WIN32` manually.

Comment: Usually all you need to do is #define WIN32 and the headers will take care of it for you.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on Anton's answer:  windows.h `#define`s `UINT` to be `unsigned int`.  That's a C macro define, not a `typedef`.  If you `#include windows.h` before you `#include mmsystem.h` the line he points to will be read as:

```
typedef unsigned int MMVERSION;
```

However, if you do it the wrong way 'round, then UINT will expand to nothing, and that line will become:

```
typedef MMVERSION;
```

That isn't valid C++ and you will get a parse error.  Which is exactly what you're getting.